# How to send a speech to text request using google_speech1 in Rust?

Tags: oauth-2.0, rust, google-speech-api

I am trying to use google_speech1 for Rust, but the documentation provides incomplete examples, which makes it very hard for me, being both new at Rust and at using Google Speech Api, to figure out how to do send a speech to text request.

More specifically, I would like to be able to send a local audio file, indicate the source language and retrieve the transcription.

Here is the closest I could find in the official documentation(https://docs.rs/google-speech1/1.0.8+20181005/google_speech1/struct.SpeechRecognizeCall.html):

```rust
use speech1::RecognizeRequest;

// As the method needs a request, you would usually fill it with the desired information
// into the respective structure. Some of the parts shown here might not be applicable !
// Values shown here are possibly random and not representative !
let mut req = RecognizeRequest::default();

// You can configure optional parameters by calling the respective setters at will, and
// execute the final call using `doit()`.
// Values shown here are possibly random and not representative !
let result = hub.speech().recognize(req)
             .doit();
```

**UPDATE**
Taking a step back, even simple examples provided on the website don't seem to run properly. Here is some sample very basic code:

```rust
pub mod speech_api_demo {
    extern crate google_speech1 as speech1;
    extern crate hyper;
    extern crate hyper_rustls;
    extern crate yup_oauth2 as oauth2;
    use oauth2::{ApplicationSecret, Authenticator, DefaultAuthenticatorDelegate, MemoryStorage};
    use speech1::Speech;
    use speech1::{Error, Result};
    use std::fs::File;
    use std::io::Read;

    #[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Default)]
    pub struct ConsoleApplicationSecret {
        pub web: Option<ApplicationSecret>,
        pub installed: Option<ApplicationSecret>,
    }

    pub fn speech_sample_demo() {
        /*
           Custom code to generate application secret
        */

        let mut file =
            File::open("C:\\Users\\YOURNAME\\.google-service-cli\\speech1-secret.json").unwrap();
        let mut data = String::new();
        file.read_to_string(&mut data).unwrap();

        use serde_json as json;
        let my_console_secret = json::from_str::<ConsoleApplicationSecret>(&data);

        assert!(my_console_secret.is_ok());
        let unwrappedConsoleSecret = my_console_secret.unwrap();
        assert!(unwrappedConsoleSecret.installed.is_some() && unwrappedConsoleSecret.web.is_none());

        let secret: ApplicationSecret = unwrappedConsoleSecret.installed.unwrap();

        /*
           Custom code to generate application secret - END
        */

        // Instantiate the authenticator. It will choose a suitable authentication flow for you,
        // unless you replace  `None` with the desired Flow.
        // Provide your own `AuthenticatorDelegate` to adjust the way it operates and get feedback about
        // what's going on. You probably want to bring in your own `TokenStorage` to persist tokens and
        // retrieve them from storage.
        let auth = Authenticator::new(
            &secret,
            DefaultAuthenticatorDelegate,
            hyper::Client::with_connector(hyper::net::HttpsConnector::new(
                hyper_rustls::TlsClient::new(),
            )),
            <MemoryStorage as Default>::default(),
            None,
        );
        let mut hub = Speech::new(
            hyper::Client::with_connector(hyper::net::HttpsConnector::new(
                hyper_rustls::TlsClient::new(),
            )),
            auth,
        );

        let result = hub.operations().get("name").doit();

        match result {
            Err(e) => match e {
                // The Error enum provides details about what exactly happened.
                // You can also just use its `Debug`, `Display` or `Error` traits
                Error::HttpError(_)
                | Error::MissingAPIKey
                | Error::MissingToken(_)
                | Error::Cancelled
                | Error::UploadSizeLimitExceeded(_, _)
                | Error::Failure(_)
                | Error::BadRequest(_)
                | Error::FieldClash(_)
                | Error::JsonDecodeError(_, _) => (println!("{}", e)),
            },
            Ok(res) => println!("Success: {:?}", res),
        }
    }
}
```

Running this code (calling speech_sample_demo) gives the following error:

> Token retrieval failed with error: Invalid Scope: 'no description
>   provided'

I also tried some very ugly code to force the scope into the request, but it did not make any difference. I am having a hard time understanding what this error means. Am I missing something in my request or is it something else getting in the way at the other end? Or maybe that api code library is just broken?

Please also note that client id and client secret provided by default don't work anymore, when I was using those it would say that account is deleted.

I then set up an OAuth 2.0 client and generated the json file which I copied over to default location and then started getting the error above. Maybe it is just me not setting Google Api account properly, but in any case would be great if someone else could try it out to see if I am the only one having those issues.

Once I get over running such a simple request, I have some more code ready to be tested that sends over an audio file, but for now it fails very early on in the process.

Comment: Have you tried doing what it says in the comments? Namely filling the fields of [RecognizeRequest](https://docs.rs/google-speech1/1.0.8+20181005/google_speech1/struct.RecognizeRequest.html) with the relevant information?

Comment: @Jmb tried just now, but was hoping if someone has used this before, could provide some basic base working code. Will try again later. Thank you.

Comment: @Jmb this is really giving me a hard time. I made some code for speech to text request, but can't even test it because I'm stuck at the following error: 

"**Token retrieval failed with error: Invalid Scope: 'no description provided'**".

Comment: Can you add the code you tried to the question along with the full error message?

Comment: @Jmb I have updated the question with the requested information.

Answer (score 2):

The error you get originates from [here](https://github.com/dermesser/yup-oauth2/blob/7e26db39ca4a17f0057c2b106bcd6fd654eb986c/src/types.rs#L40) and means that the OAuth [scope](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/scope/) you used *when generating your credentials file* doesn't allow you to access the Google speech API. So the problem is not in your Rust code, but instead in the script you used to generate your OAuth access tokens.

Basically, this means that when you generated your OAuth json file, you requested access to the Google API in a general way, but you didn't say which specific APIs you meant to use. According to [this document](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes), you need to request access to the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` scope.

Comment: I've looked at the source code of the library, and it injects that url in each request (or is that code broken?), I even tried injecting it myself, but in any case it is something that should be in request (as far as I understand it). Have you tried making that code work on your end or can you specifically give me the steps I am missing, if any? I appreciate your efforts, but this remains a question about a Rust library that allows to use Google Api and I'm looking for proof that it works (and what to fix to make it work), as there is so little information about it online.

Comment: The library is right to inject that URL. The step you are missing is _before_ you get to the rust part, when you are generating the json file containing the OAuth access tokens. How exactly have you generated that json file? With what code or what tool and what parameters?

Comment: I logged into Google API console, created a project, enabled google speech to text api for it, then created a oauth2 client with type other and then once it was created I was able to download the JSON file, then am loading that from app with the code i posted.

Comment: I'm not sure what you call a "_oauth2 client with type other_". According to the OAuth2 RFC sections [4.1.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.1.1) and [3.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-3.3), when the client requests an authorization it should specify the `scope` of that authorization. So did you give the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` URL anywhere in your "_oauth2 client with type other_"?

Comment: As stated since the beginning I was hoping to get confirmation from someone that this library is actually working, but I can't argue with the fact that there indeed seems to be something wrong with my Oauth2 client, trying to figure it out. Now I got to adding scope to it, but next step requires validation but asks for validation url and I have no idea what to put, it's becoming clear that I don't know much about using those Google Api... will report here if I get it to work, in the meantime if you have steps for creating a oauth2 client compatible with this library, that would be nice :).

Comment: Well I've never written an oauth2 client, but I have performed the oauth2 client operations by hand in  a web browser (for the Amazon API, not Google). [This page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent) should show you what requests to make (choose "OAUTH 2.0 ENDPOINT" instead of "JS CLIENT LIBRARY" to see the http requests you need to make).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the flow param to Authenticator. This is how you get the access token. You create an Enum using FlowType.

example:

```
    use oauth2::{ApplicationSecret, Authenticator, DefaultAuthenticatorDelegate, MemoryStorage,FlowType};



let Flo = FlowType::InstalledInteractive;
let auth = Authenticator::new(
                &secret,
                DefaultAuthenticatorDelegate,
                hyper::Client::with_connector(hyper::net::HttpsConnector::new(
                    hyper_rustls::TlsClient::new(),
                )),
                <MemoryStorage as Default>::default(),
                None,)
```

See here: https://docs.rs/yup-oauth2/1.0.3/yup_oauth2/enum.FlowType.html

Not exactly easy to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

I made this work via service accounts by doing this

```
    let https = hyper_rustls::HttpsConnectorBuilder::new()
        .with_native_roots()
        .https_only()
        .enable_http1()
        .build();

    let service_account_key: oauth2::ServiceAccountKey = oauth2::read_service_account_key(
        &"PATH_TO_SERVICE_ACCOUNT.json".to_string(),
    )
    .await
    .unwrap();

    let auth = oauth2::ServiceAccountAuthenticator::builder(service_account_key)
        .build()
        .await
        .unwrap();

    let hub = Speech::new(hyper::Client::builder().build(https), auth);
```